# focus() under Firefox not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, firefox, gwt

I am trying to prevent a user from writing on a `contentedtiable` element. For this purpose I am retrieving the parent container of the caret and check if it is the textarea with ID `dnd-textarea`.

The code below works perfectly fine on Chrome but fails on Firefox. The logging output of `preventWritingOnTextArea()` reveals that under Firefox the parent didn't change but is still `dnd-textarea` instead of the `InlinePanel` with ID `newId`.

```java
private native Node getCaretParent() /*-{

    var target = null;

    if($wnd.getSelection) {
        target = $wnd.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        return ((target.nodeType===1) ? target:target.parentNode);
    }
    else if($doc.selection) {
        target = $doc.selection.createRange().parentElement();
    }

    return target;
}-*/;
```

In the `onKeyPress()` method of my textarea I check if the carret tries to write on it. If so, I branch into `preventWritingOnTextArea()` to prevent that.

```java
@Override
public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {

    Node parent = getCaretParent();

    GWT.log("Caret parent: " + parent);

    if(parent == textarea.getElement()) {                       
        preventWritingOnTextArea();         
    }           
}
```

The method `preventWritingOnTextAread()` is supposed to add a new `InlinePanel` and remove the focus from the textarea by setting focus on this new panel. Imho this can only mean that `focus()` does not work on Firefox as expected and/or does something else.

```java
private void preventWritingOnTextArea() {

    GWT.log("preventWritingOnTextArea()");

    InlineLabel textWrapper = new InlineLabel();

    int pos = getCursorPosition(textarea.getElement());

    if(pos == 0) {
        textarea.getElement().insertFirst(textWrapper.getElement());
    } else {
        textarea.getElement().appendChild(textWrapper.getElement());
    }

    String newId = "wrap-"+(nextId++);

    // Tried that too but this loses the focus completely under Firefox.
    //textarea.getElement().blur();

    textWrapper.getElement().setId(newId);
    textWrapper.getElement().focus();   

    Node parent = getCaretParent(); 
    Element newParent = parent.cast();  
    GWT.log("New parent " + newParent.getId());
}
```

How can I make this work under Firefox and yeah.. all the other browser too..

Yes, I have tried to `blur()` first on `textarea` and then set focus back on `textWrapper` but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Firefox did not want to do it the way it was supposed to work. My solution for now is to mark the text of new `span` element (which is obviously empty) to actually get the focus on it. It is ugly but then again we are talking here about web-development, right? Credits to @TimDown [for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse/2838358#2838358).

```
private void preventWritingOnTextArea() {

    GWT.log("preventWritingOnTextArea()");

    InlineLabel textWrapper = new InlineLabel();

    // ...

    textWrapper.getElement().setId(newId);
    textWrapper.getElement().focus();

    // Firefox didn't want to play with us.
    markText(textWrapper.getElement());
}

private native void markText(Element element) /*-{

    win = $wnd;
    var doc = win.document, sel, range;

    if (win.getSelection && doc.createRange) {      
        sel = win.getSelection();
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);

    } else if (doc.body.createTextRange) {      
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    }       
}-*/;
```